# Hacer correr slider automáticamente

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap

Quisiera saber cómo hago para que un slider corra por si solo. Solamente está corriendo con las flechas. Éste es mi código

```js
(function() {
  var sliderImages = document.querySelectorAll('.image'),
    arrowLeft = document.querySelector('#left-arrow'),
    arrowRight = document.querySelector('#right-arrow'),
    currentImg = 0;

  function initSlider() {
    resetSlider();

    sliderImages[0].style.display = 'block';
  }

  function resetSlider() {
    for (var i = 0; i < sliderImages.length; i++) {
      sliderImages[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }

  function toLeft() {
    resetSlider();
    sliderImages[currentImg - 1].style.display = 'block';
    currentImg--;
  }

  function toRight() {
    resetSlider();
    sliderImages[currentImg + 1].style.display = 'block';
    currentImg++;
  }

  arrowLeft.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentImg === 0) {
      currentImg = sliderImages.length;
    }

    toLeft();
  });

  arrowRight.addEventListener('click', function() {
    if (currentImg === sliderImages.length - 1) {
      currentImg = -1;
    }

    toRight();
  });

  initSlider();
})();
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div id="slider">
    <div class="image image-one">
      <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
        <div class="contenedor">
          <h1><strong>BUSCAR </strong>LO QUE<br>SOÑAMOS</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-1 btn-1e ">NUESTROS PROYECTOS</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image image-two">
      <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
        <div class="contenedor">
          <h1><strong>BUSCAR </strong>LO QUE<br>SOÑAMOS</h1>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-1 btn-1e ">NUESTROS PROYECTOS</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!--<div class="image image-three">
                        <div class="vertical-align-wrapper">
                            <span>Slide 3</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>-->
  </div>
  <div class="arrows">
    <div id="left-arrow" class="arrow">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
    <div id="right-arrow" class="arrow">
      <a href=""></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hola Mariano, ¿estás usando Bootstrap o algún plugin de Bootstrap? Si es así, deberías indicar cuál.

Comment: Si si estoy usando bootstraps

Answer (score 1):

Podrias disparar un evento click cada cierto tiempo, eso haria que pasaran los sliders.

```
function trigger(element,type){
    var event;
    if (document.createEvent) {
        event = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        event.initEvent(type, true, true);
      } else {
        event = document.createEventObject();
        event.eventType = type;
      }
      event.eventName = type;
      if (document.createEvent) {
        element.dispatchEvent(event);
      } else {
        element.fireEvent("on" + event.eventType, event);
      }
}

//Simula un click en la flecha de la derecha
trigger(arrowRight,'click');

//Hace movimiento automatico cada 3 sg
setInterval(function(){trigger(arrowRight,'click');},3000);
```

si se quiere que vaya hacia la izquierda cambia arrowRight por arrowLeft

Comment: Gracias Javier, entonces si añado ese fragmento de código a lo que tenia el carousel giraría tambien solamente?

Comment: Si, ese codigo se compagina con el que ya tenias, es mas usa tus eventos de 'click' en los botones, lo que hace es lanzar esos eventos. pero solo lo haria una vez, la edito

Comment: Muchas gracias Javier anduvo perfecto!